# Is it possible to vectorise the sequential update of the elements of a vector in R?

Tags: r, vectorization

Is it possible to vectorise code like the following?

```
length(x) <- 100;
x[1]      <- 1;
y         <- rnorm(100);

for(i in 2:100) {
    x[i] <- 2 * y[i] * x[i-1];
}
```

I appreciate that this is a trivial example, but it serves to illustrate the idea.

I often need to write code where the i-th value in a vector depends on the (i-1)-th value and if possible, I'd like to write this without needing a `for` loop, as profiling suggests the functions with this type of operation are the major bottlenecks in my code.

Is this operation vectorizable so I do not need to use a `for()` loop in the calculation?

Comment: You have found the weakest link of R:) I am afraid the only general solution is to drop the computation to C level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, if you want a vectorised solution you need to solve the [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).

Comment: Thanks for the link, +1. I'm struggling, with my limited math, to turn that Wikipedia page info into something that solves to OP's problem. If it is not too involved, could you expand on your answer to suggest a way to solve the OP's Q directly?

Answer (score 5):

In the example you have you could work out the formula for x[i] and see if it can be vectorized. In this case I think cumprod might work.

```
x <- c(1, cumprod(2*y)[1:99])
```

For some cases case you can also use the `filter` command in convolution or recursive mode. See `?filter`

However if it is isn't possible to work out a formula for the n'th value that fits one of the molds above, you could try using a package like `inline` or `Rcpp` to write this in loop in C/C++.

Comment: I don't get the same answer as @kaybenleroll 's Question with the cumprod solution. I don't think this is right here either, the `for` loop is not cumulative over 1, ..., n, just a function of `n-1`.

Comment: It's just a minor indexing error: the correct answer is `c(1, cumprod(2*y[-1]))`

Answer (score 1):

The interior of this plot command is equivalent. Rather interesting to repeatedly run it:

plot(c(1, 2^(2:length(x)-1)*cumprod(rnorm(99) )) )

Answer (score 1):

You can write the non-vertorized code in C++:

```
library(inline)
myfun <- cxxfunction(signature(y="numeric"), body='
Rcpp::NumericVector yvec(y);
int ysize = yvec.size();
Rcpp::NumericVector result(ysize);
if (ysize > 0) {
    result[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < ysize; i++) {
        result[i] = 2 * yvec[i] * result[i-1];
    }
}
return result;
', plugin="Rcpp")
```

Then call this function from R:

```
y <- rnorm(100);
x <- myfun(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have full details on this yet, but it looks the function `filter()` is going to be useful to do what I need.